# Стек и переменные функции

Tags: c, стек

Правильно ли я понимаю, что при вызове функции от стека сразу откусывается кусок, достаточный для всех размещений?

```
void f(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    // ...
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        // ...
        for (int k = 0; k < j; ++k)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Очевидно, что лучше сразу зарезервировать память под переменные `i`, `j` и `k`.

Где искать информацию по этому вопросу - в стандарте языка или в мануалах компилятора?

Я интересуюсь этим вопросом, потому что хочу лучше понять, как безопасно и правильно использовать `goto` и `вложенные функции`.

Comment: Переменные могут вообще быть не на стеке, а в регистрах. Информацию ищите в дизассемблированном коде функции, но вообще вас, как программиста, этот вопрос не должен особо волновать. Если не понятно что-то с `goto`, то про него и спрашивайте.

Comment: Зависит от конкретной реализации компилятора.

Comment: Вроде как зависит и от компилятора, и от ОС. Скажем, выделяется 1 Мб _виртуальной_ памяти. _Физической_ памяти будет выделено столько страниц, сколько необходимо.

Comment: Сам язык этого не требует. Но большинство реализаций поступает именно так. Разумеется, если эти переменные вообще будут размещены в стеке. Ну и, понятное дело, VLA являются исключением - их сразу не откусишь. При чем здесь безопасное использование `goto` - не ясно. Вложенных функций в С нет.